# Changing value of text field with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, textfield

I have a form input text field, and I want to change the text inside of the text field when the user clicks a button. I can get the specific textfield with jQuery, but cannot change the text with .val(). Is there another way this can be done, or am I doing something wrong.

Here is the text field:

```
<input type="text" name="textBox" id="Stage 1text" size="20" value="Enter Current Comp." align="center">
```

Then I use this to identify and change the text field. where in this case stage = "Stage 1" and dance is the string I want to place in the text field.

```
str = "#" + stage + 'text';
alert(str + '::' + dance); // confirm that strings are correct
jQuery(str).val(dance);
```

Comment: An ID should not have spaces. `Stage 1text` is an invalid ID

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that an id couldn't have spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ID should not have spaces. Stage 1text is an invalid ID

Add an underscore instead of space

```
<input type="text" name="textBox" id="Stage_1text" size="20" value="Enter Current Comp." align="center">
```

and try below,

```
//           v--- assuming this will be Stage_1
str = "#" + stage + 'text';
alert(str + '::' + dance); // confirm that strings are correct
jQuery(str).val(dance);
```

incase if stage is returned from backend.. then simply replace space with _

```
 str = "#" + stage.replace(/ /g,"_") + 'text';
```

Answer (score 1):

`id` attributes should not contain spaces.

You could change your code like so:

```
<input type="text" name="textBox" id="Stage_1text" size="20" value="Enter Current Comp." align="center">

str = "#" + stage.replace(' ','_') + 'text';
alert(str + '::' + dance); // confirm that strings are correct
jQuery(str).val(dance);
```